# Openssl support for ruby not found in passenger installation on ruby 1.9.2 with ubuntu & rvm

Tags: ubuntu, nginx, openssl, passenger

Here is a strange problem. In irb, require 'openssl' return true. Went into subdir returned by 'which passenger-install-nginx-module' and executing the passenger-install-nginx-module. It returns that openssl support for ruby not found.

Followed the instruction below to build openssl successfully:

```
sudo apt-get install libssl-dev
cd ~/.rvm/src/ruby-1.9.2-p290/ext/openssl  #ruby p290 installed by rvm
ruby extconf.rb
make && make install
```

However the passenger-install-nginx-module always prompts 'openssl support for ruby not found'.

Any thoughts about the problem? Thanks.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here is what worked (installed openssl support for ruby):

```
$rvm remove 1.9.2
$rvm pkg install openssl
$rvm install 1.9.2 --with-openssl-dir=$HOME/.rvm/usr
```

Then cd /vol/www/myapp/current, install passenger.

```
$rvmsudo gem install passenger
$rvmsudo passenger-install-nginx-module
```

Comment: On RackSpace Cloud, I needed `rvm package install openssl` and `rvm install 1.9.2 --with-openssl-dir=/usr/share/ruby-rvm/usr`. Just pay attention to where openssl is installed.

Comment: Regarding the openssl-dir, the generic option is to use the rvm home path variable: --with-openssl-dir=$rvm_path/usr

Answer (score 2):

After compiling and installing ruby, from the source you go to the ext/openssl dir and compile it

as in cd to : /usr/local/src/ruby-1.8.7-p22/ext/openssl (or whatever)

```
sudo ruby extconf.rb
make
make install
```

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned by user938363, here is a link to full details:

https://rvm.io/packages/openssl/